# How do I show a bool property as Yes|No in the property grid?

Tags: .net, winforms, propertygrid

I know I can do this by writing custom type descriptors etc., however given how simple this requirement is; am I missing an easy way of doing it.

Being able to set the string for "true" and "false" in the BooleanConverter may be all I need, but the standared BooleanConverter does not seem to let you set custom strings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll have to customize it.  Like this:

```
class YesNoConverter : BooleanConverter {
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        if (value is bool && destinationType == typeof(string)) {
            return values[(bool)value ? 1 : 0];
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        string txt = value as string;
        if (values[0] == txt) return false;
        if (values[1] == txt) return true;
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    private string[] values = new string[] { "No", "Yes" };
}
```

Sample usage:

```
class MyControl : Control {
    [TypeConverter(typeof(YesNoConverter))]
    public bool Prop { get; set; }
}
```

You get no help from System.Globalization to make this work in other languages.

Comment: Thanks, close, but when I double click on the value I get an Error Dlg "Property value is not valid" / "Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Boolean'."

Comment: Ugh, pita.  Put a PropertyGrid on a form to debug this at runtime.

Comment: You might need System::Convert::ToBoolean(value) instead of the cast to bool.

Comment: @Ian: Your GetStandardValues method should not return your array of strings but an array of bools. And since the base BooleanConverter already does it, you can completely remove this method.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid implementing a custom converter by using an enum:

```
public enum YesNo{No,Yes}

...

[Browsable(true)]
public YesNo IsValueSet {get;set)

[Browsable(false)] //also consider excluding it from designer serialization
public bool ValueSetAsBool 
{
   get { return Convert.ToBoolean((byte)IsValueSet); }
   set { IsValueSet = value ? YesNo.Yes : YesNo.No; }
}
```

As is, this solution isn't localizable, and you'd have to implement an enum for every permutation of "On/Off" value pairs you wanted to use. But, it's the simple answer for a one-off.